"background-clip: text;" issue. I want the outline to this text to be bigger
the problem
problem 2, if i changed the webkit-text-fill-color to transparent.
main h2{
    margin: 0;
    animation: flow 10s ease-in-out infinite;
    background: linear-gradient(-60deg, hsl(134, 85%, 66%), hsl(135, 100%, 62%), #93f9b9);
    --webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    background-size: 350%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(34, 35, 42);
    font-family: "Sen", sans-serif;
    font-size: 350%;
}

Title explains it basically
I've tried searching for a solution. Changing background size is one of them.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question, and not just snippets that lack context.

What do you mean by outline in this context?
